# How can I update a boolean column in a table with BulkOperations?

Tags: c#, .net, package, sql-delete, sqlbulktools

I am using an open-source library to do this. It's called SqlBulkTools.

I just want to update a column by using primary IDs to set the value to 'true' if it's being marked for deletion, rather than actually deleting it.

I've included the code to do this, but I'm encountering an error that states the input array is longer than the number of columns in the table.

```cs
  public static async Task<int> BulkSetToDeleteAsync(string connectionString, dynamic[] primaryIds, string tableName, string primaryKeyName, string columnName, CancellationToken ct)
  {
      if (primaryIds is null || primaryIds.Length == 0)
      {
          return await Task.FromResult(0);
      }

      string sql = $"UPDATE [{tableName}] Set [{columnName}] = 1 Where [{primaryKeyName}] IN ({string.Join(", ", primaryIds)})";

      var query = new BulkOperations()
          .Setup()
          .ForCollection(primaryIds).WithTable(tableName)
          .WithBulkCopySettings(new BulkCopySettings { EnableStreaming = true, SqlBulkCopyOptions = SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity })
          .AddColumn(columnName)
          .BulkInsertOrUpdate().MatchTargetOn(primaryKeyName);

      using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

      return await query.CommitAsync(connection, null, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
```

I want to use an open-source tool called SqlBulkTools to set the value of a boolean column in a table to 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about this [`SqlBulkTools`](https://github.com/olegil/SqlBulkTools) library then it works on the base of `MERGE` command ([source](https://github.com/olegil/SqlBulkTools/blob/d33329bd077e75c9f65aa3969318bd7b0821f1c0/SqlBulkTools/BulkUpdate.cs#L179C40-L179C45)) so you need to provide full input data, not only the ids. You need to transform you ids collection into collection representing rows, you can try leveraging [custom mappings](https://github.com/olegil/SqlBulkTools#custom-mappings). Something along these lines (not tested):

```
static async Task<int> BulkSetToDeleteAsync<T>(string connectionString, T[] primaryIds, string tableName, string primaryKeyName, string columnName, CancellationToken ct)
{
    if (primaryIds is null || primaryIds.Length == 0)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    var query = new BulkOperations()
        .Setup()
        .ForCollection(primaryIds.Select(pk => new { Id = pk, Deleted = 1 }))
        .WithTable(tableName)
        .WithBulkCopySettings(new BulkCopySettings { EnableStreaming = true, SqlBulkCopyOptions = SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity })
        .AddAllColumns()
        .CustomColumnMapping(x => x.Id, primaryKeyName) 
        .CustomColumnMapping(x => x.Deleted, columnName) 
        .BulkInsertOrUpdate()
        .MatchTargetOn(x => x.Id);

    using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    return await query.CommitAsync(connection, null, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```